# Altium track width DRC error on corners

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, error, drc

I just ran the DRC check in Altium for my PCB and I get errors on trace width for every trace segments on the board.

What is the reason for this ? It generated thousands of errors even tho all the traces are 4 to 5 mils wide.

All tracks width rules are set to >= 4 mils

This is the error message I get under "Rule Violations" : 
*Clearance Constraint (Gap=3.5mil) (All),(All)* 
Clearance Constraint: (Collision < 3.5mil) Between Track (52761.3mil,31343.2mil)(52769.499mil,31343.2mil) on Solder Side And Arc (52769.499mil,31340.4mil) on Solder Side

[image]
[image]

**Edit: It also affects trace much much larger than 3.5 mils**

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Are those white rings vias?  or some other thing you've placed on the corners?  You wouldn't normally  see rings like that at a bend in a track.

Comment: @Daniel I added it to the question.
and PeterBennett Nope, these are only routed, no vias, no nothing, pure corners

Comment: Well, the error message says the violation is between a track and an arc - so somehow  arcs were placed where the tracks bend.

Comment: Are the elements you're connecting on the same nets? (Are they connected to the same net name in your schematic?)

Comment: Yes they are on the same nets @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was in the clearance rule I selected "Any nets" by mistake which meant the rule was applied to any segment no matter what net it is from, changing it back to "Different nets only" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The image you've attached is for Minimum Clearance between components. There should be another dialog that defines the minimum and maximum trace widths. Double check that they are correct.

Comment: It doesn't work not matter what I put, all my tolerance, clearance, trace width are >4 mils

Answer (score 0):

What ARCs is it referring to? From your picture, I can't see any.

Use the PCB Filter "IsArc" to see where these mystery geometries are coming from.

Did you accidentally convert your vias to free pads? I could see that causing some issues for the DRC.